# How to sum cells across two matrices in different datasets?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've researched previous answers, nothing seems relevant to this question.

I have a simple matrix, showing data from "Dataset A" - counts in the rows and month/years in the columns.

I have a second matrix, showing data from "Dataset B" with the same layout.

I wish to create a third matrix, or add a total line to the second matrix, showing the sum of each month's figures. See screenshot;

Image showing dataset A (orange header) and dataset B (blue header) and items I wish to sum

[image]

I have tried adding a new row to the dataset B matrix and using the following formula -

```
=SUM(Fields!Counts.Value) + Sum(Fields!Counts.Value, DatasetA")
```

However this fails to take into account the month groupings from Dataset A, and instead sums the correct number from Dataset B with the *total* number from Dataset A - not just the figure for the appropriate month.

How can I make this sum work, ensuring that only the relevant months are summed across both datasets?

Thanks!

Update: Using the LOOKUP function I have made a little progress but still have been unable to sum the two numbers (See image, below). I tried the following lookup expression to build the total;

> =Sum(Fields!Counts.Value) + LOOKUP(Fields!ReceivedMonth.Value, Fields!ReceivedMonth.Value, Fields!Counts.Value, "DatasetA")

But it appears that I'm unable to SUM the **Fields!Counts.Value, "DatasetA"** inside the lookup (it throws a syntax error), so the total result is displaying at the total from DatasetB plus 1.

[Image showing result of LOOKUP - not quite correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7GQ4.png)

Comment: Possible solution using `LOOKUP()` function. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b5503eb-cfa2-4ebf-83bf-7ecc1232bdab/add-two-different-custom-calculated-fields-from-two-different-datasets-in-matrix?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Based on the edit, you'll probably need `LOOKUPSET()` which looks up the full set of a field from another dataset.  I'm not totally sure that you'll get exactly what you want with that either, however. You might need to use the group name in your lookup as the scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me to that discussion - I think I'm on the right path with LOOKUP, but I updated my question above with my attempt to use LOOKUP  - any ideas where I'm going wrong?